Lost Password, Recovery will not work due to a Dependency
I am not a confident Ubuntu user but changed my password due to unexplained usage issues. I copied carefully the suggested Ubuntu password, but it will not work, neither will the previous one, nor removing the last entry in case I hit backspace.
I tried changing it using this article How do I reset a lost administrative password?, but it will not complete due to a dependency for a USB stick I have not used for ages because it was causing problems.
From GRUB I select the latest Kernel in recovery mode. The screen is pink with the options spread to the right of the options box at increasing indent.
I selected Root Drop to root shell prompt. The result:
[OK] started Avahi mDNS-SD Stack
[OK] Started Cups Scheduler
[OK] Reached target Printer Support
     Started Save/Restore Sound Card State...    
[OK] Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State
[OK] Reached target Sound Card
[Time] Timed out waiting for device/dev/disk/by-id/usb-UGREEN_MassStorageClass_123426789ABCDE-010
[Depend] Dependency failed for/mnt/usb-UGREEN_MassStorageClass_123426789ABCDE-010

Then I tried again by another option on the same article by editing the Kernel.
From GRUB I selected my latest Kernel and pressed e. The result:
set params, with Linux 6.5.0-41-generic
record fail
Load-video
gfx mode $ Linux-gtx-mode
insmod gzio
If [xtgrub_platforms=xxen l: then insmod lzopio fi
insmod part-gpt
insmod ext2
Search -no floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ifzbfc8b-34be-4a7b-93d3-828c6975le71
echo 'LoadingLinux6.5.0-41-generic... 
Linux /boot/unilinuz-6.5.0-41 generic root = if2bfc06 ro apm = power_off
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41 generic
There is no line Starting Kernel

If you can see the problem can you advise how to delete the dependency when I can't log in and advice on the best way to recover my password?

Your first solution is the correct one. To stop the error message in Ubuntu 24.04 do the following:

Boot with your Ubuntu USB and choose Try Ubuntu.

Once the Panel appears, click on <size> Volume (in my case 31 GB Volume).

In the opened window locate the etc folder.

Right-click on it and choose Open in terminal and continue from point 5.


If you need to find the name of your partition, use:
   sudo blkid

and then you can mount it with:
   sudo mount /dev/device_name /mnt

In the above command change device_name to your partition, for example sda4.
Run:
   cd mnt


Make a copy of your fstab to keep it as a backup:
sudo cp fstab fstab.old


Run:
sudo gedit fstab


In fstab locate the line that has usb-UGREEN and add a # to the beginning of the line.

Save and close fstab.

Restart your computer.

Drop to root shell prompt, and use the same link in your question (How do I reset a lost administrative password?) to reset your password.



Thanks again. The sudo blkid came out different (as I'm in Trial?) but gave me the UUID. I got the device from Gparted and tried the device name and UUID in both case I got "mount: /mnt: special device  does not exist. You enabled me to copy all of my folders and files out onto an SSD and it is probably time for a clean boot. Your help has been gratefully appreciated but I think I must re-install as a single boot. Windows 11 is an bloatware advertising channel.

The answer in the end was simple.I plugged in the device causing the dependency, the dependency nolonger existed and the passord was changed. Thank you again Amar
